# Spring Boot get Authentication Principal

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm using Spring Boot Parent version 1.5.16.

I need to use current user information and now I use @AuthenticationPrincipal annotation.

But I have to write this annotation for each method. I think this is not a best practice because I have more than 200+ methods. Is there any other suggestion to inject Authentication Principal globally or class level?

Comment: I assume you want to use the user information in a web project? If so, think about using @ ControllerAdvice or @ ModelAdvice. This enables you to create a global attribute for your ViewModel and you can use this attribute in every Controller.

Comment: Use SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() ;)